# Does anyone know the location of detailed documentation covering the use of watir with html tags such as li ul td to navigate the DOM?

Tags: dom, tags, watir

I have encountered unexpected results from the following code.
I'm getting -list- values from the -unordered list- located after the one I target
with "Employee_error_list"
why doesn't the response confine itself to the content
between the -unordered-list- and /-unordered-list- ?

```
theList = browser.ul(:id, "Employee_error_list")
theList.lis.each do |li|
  puts li.text
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example (ie sample HTML and the unexpected output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To answer the question about documentation

The list type elements you mention are [ElementCollection](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/ElementCollection) objects.

- The best documentation I've found is the [Watir-Webdriver RDoc Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames).
- A list of these can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130719051431/http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Collections+of+HTML+Elements).
- A full [list of elements supported by Watir is here](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir)

You can traverse an ElementCollection by using the code example you give:

```
theList = browser.ul(:id, "Employee_error_list")
theList.lis.each do |li|
  puts li.text
end
```

As far as why the elements returned are not confined to the `ul` you specify, I'm not sure without seeing an example of the page HTML.  The way you are doing it *should* work, but if you're seeing unexpected behavior it could be a bug.